# Fix VB6 component warning when registering in COM+

Tags: com, vb6, 32bit-64bit, com+

I'm supporting an old Web Application that has some VB6 components and I've found on certain servers I get the below warnings when I'm installing the components in COM+. I've seen some posts that say you need to run MMC with a -32 parameter but that doesn't seem to make a difference. It says to "check the registry value for the following key." But doesn't say what to check for or what to do.  Anybody have any suggestions?

> A registry value was changed while installing the following component
> into a COM+ Application. If you are experiencing activation problems
> with this component then please check the registry value for the
> following key.
>
> Component: C:\some path\my.dll
>
> Registry Key: CLSID{some guid}\InProcServer32
>
> Process Name: RunDll32.exe  Comsvcs.dll file version:  not loaded

Comment: Are you installing the components manually or through an installation program?  If the former, are you using an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I'm installing them "manually" through the Component Services add in, and yes I am logged in as the Administrator and I've turned UAC off.  My guess is it has something do to with the addition of the "SysWow64" section of the registry but am not sure.  The "Please check ... " is just very unclear.  Check it for what?

Answer (score 0):

This was a long time ago but for similar issues it might be caused because the VB6 components are 32 bits and the OS is 64 bits.

Try registering the component in 32 bits using:  `C:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe`

and also run the 32 bits version of the COM+ app `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mmc comexp.msc /32`